# Regex - how to find multiple import statement matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all occurrences of a js import statement in a string of text

For example in this string:

`import $ from "./components/jquery.js"; import dirtyFormUnload from "./components/dirtyFormUnload.js";`

I'd like to match

`import $ from "./components/jquery.js";`

and

`import dirtyFormUnload from "./components/dirtyFormUnload.js";`

The regex I've put together is below, but it matches the entire string once, instead of each individual import statement

`import\s+.*\s+from\s+['""].*\.js[^\s;]*[\s;]?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your regex statement is getting `greedy`, meaning that the first `.*` is matching as much as it can, including the next input statement. One way to fix this is to prevent it from matching `;` characters like this:

```
import\s+[^;]*\s+from\s+['""][^;]*\.js[^\s;]*[\s;]?
```